# Is there any way to see the context of a log message in Graylog2?

Tags: graylog

I've installed a Graylog2 server and begun collecting log data. It all worked fine, but as soon as I found the first Java exception with attendant stack-trace, a problem occurred to me. How can I see the exception and the following (or preceding) log lines together?

Looking at the [forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/graylog2/context), others have had the same problem, but it doesn't seem like the the issue has been addressed yet in Graylog.

As a work around I can search for messages from the same source as the line I want context for and limit results to a small timeframe, but what I really want is something akin to Splunk's raw log view.

Am I missing a feature in Graylog or is there and addon or patch I can install to add the functionality?

<del>(PS: I'm not committed to Graylog yet, so if there are opensource alternatives I'd be happy to hear about them)</del>

***Edit**: I found out how to use NXLog's `xm_multiline`module to group the lines of exceptions into one message, but finding context is still painful.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade. Graylog 2.0, released in 2016, has the "search for surrounding messages" functionality ([changelog link](http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.1/pages/changelog.html#graylog-2-0-0)).

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible. There is an open [issue](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-web-interface/issues/150)  for this functionality.